# How to find covariance matrix of a AWGN noise vector $n$ with variance =$\sigma^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, expected-value, covariance

Suppose $n=\sigma*randn(1000,1)+ u$ is a noise vector.
How can i simulate the covariance matrix $E[n.n^T]$ in MATLAB such that we get
$E[n.n^T]= \sigma^2I$ in the simulation with rank=1000.

If we multiply vector $n$ with its transpose, rank will be $1$ only,but the rank of $E[n.n^T]$ should be 1000,right?

In general how do you take expectation E of a $[n.n^T]$ matrix.
I have seen some answers but didn't understand correctly.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! Could you please add more details and context to your question? For example, you mention that you didn't understand some answers. What answers, and what exactly didn't you understand?

Comment: I have seen some answers in the stack exchange itself. Specifically I did not get any answers regarding how to take Expectation of a matrix $[n.n^T]$ in MATLAB. Also I have read AWGN noise VECTOR with zero mean will have a covariance matrix looks like $E[n.n^T]= \sigma^2I$. I just want to know how you can simulate  it in matlab. Thanks for the response.